# Random string to rename a File on upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I took this code from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp and I am just playing about with it:

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

I was wondering how I would make it create a random file name when its uploaded so files with the same name can be uploaded multiple times.

Comment: `mt_rand()`, `uniqid()`, add a timestamp, hash the file's contents... there are many ways.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Answer (score 2):

See

http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

or

http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php

depending on your need

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_name_here = 'file_' . rand(0, 10000) . '.' . end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $new_name_here);`
```

The second parameter of [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) choose the new file name.